# Can't access data in array after mapping it from api pull

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api

So I have pulled some data from an api using a fetch in a React app, then I have used .map to get the data I want into arrays that I am trying to present in a table sort of format.

When I log the mapped arrays it presents the data I am after, but when I try access it to present specific elements of it it's returning undefined.

If the array in the console log shows that it has elements name and age, is there something I am doing wrong to get undefined when I try and access it? Or maybe I am accessing it the wrong way. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function getMap(results) {
   return results.map((res) => {
       return {name: res.name, age: res.age}
}

fetch(URL)
   .then(result) {
       let x = getMap(result.result);
       console.log(x);

///// the console log shows an array [{name: 'Peter', age: 30}]

      console.log(x.name);

///// console log returns undefined
})
```

Comment: Where are the closing brackets of the `then()`? Also, I assume the syntax error `.then(result) {` is just a typo.

Comment: thats an error in typing question, wasn't a direct copy from program. Will fix now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you aren't accessing the array correctly. Remember an array is like a "list" of things, in this case, objects. Each object has two properties, name and age. The way you are trying to access it in your second console.log, you are trying to access a .name property on the array itself. This is pretty basic, but to access an item in an array, you pass an index (starting at zero), like so: `myArray[0]`. So to access the name property of the first item in your array, you would use `x[0].name`. To iterate over the entire array, you could do `x.forEach(item => console.log(item.name))`

Comment: It still returns as undefined trying to access a specific index [0] , if I take exactly what the console log returns looking at the entire thing each one looks like: 0: {name: 'tom'} then the following would be 1: {name: 'pete'}

Comment: Turns out the group was inside another array, so I can access if I go x[0][0].name, how would I go about changing that foreach loop to include that

Comment: Oh, the reason that is happening is because you are adding the array during your map function. The map function takes an array and returns an array. You dont need to manually wrap items in an array, they are already in an array. I thought the opening array was a typo so i didnt say anything.

Comment: So were you able to solve your problem or still unresolved?